# Elasticsearch 2.2 Java API minimum field length

Tags: java, elasticsearch

With following code i want to search for first_name and last_name:

```
TransportClient client = elasticSearchProvider.getClient();
    SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("migranthire").setTypes("refugee").setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH);


    //Queries
    BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query + "*"));
    queryBuilder.should(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query + "", "first_name", "last_name").boost(2).operator(MatchQueryBuilder.Operator.AND));

    if (talent != null && talent == 0) {
        queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(0 + "").field("talent"));
    }
    //Active ones
    queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(1 + "").field("active"));


    requestBuilder.setQuery(queryBuilder);
    requestBuilder.setFrom(start);
    requestBuilder.setSize(limit);
    requestBuilder.setFetchSource(new String[]{"id"}, null);
```

The only thing i can't find out is -> How can i filter out the search results, where first_name and last_name is empty or where the length of that fields is <1?